# Bookshelf js fetchAll withRelated option returns empty relation object

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

When I `.fetchAll({ withRelated: 'backfire' });` I end up with a property called backfire in my output, with a value of {}. In knex debug mode I clearly see `select "backfire".* from "backfire" where "backfire"."id" in (?);` which works when copy/pasted into the sqlite3 console (after putting in valid IDs of course). So I know my model must be somewhat correct.

### Knex Migration

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("backfire", function(table) {
    table.increments("id").primary();
    table.string("response").notNullable();
    table.string("created_by").notNullable();
    table.timestamps();
}).then(function(){
        return knex.schema.createTable("backfireTrigger", function(table) {
            table.increments("id").primary();
            table.string("trigger").notNullable();
            table.integer("backfire_id").unsigned().notNullable().references("id").inTable("backfire");
            table.string("created_by").notNullable();
            table.timestamps();
        });
    });
};
```

### Models.js

```
module.exports = function(bookshelf) {

var Backfire = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'backfire',
    backfireTriggers: function() {
      return this.hasMany(BackfireTrigger);
    }
});

var BackfireTrigger = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'backfireTrigger',
    backfire: function() {
      return this.belongsTo(Backfire);
    }
});

return {
  Backfire: Backfire,
  BackfireTrigger: BackfireTrigger
};
```

}

### My usage

```
function getAllTriggers() {
    var self = this;
    return new self.models.BackfireTrigger()
    .fetchAll({
        withRelated: ['backfire']
    });
}
```

Comment: Which underlying database are you using? I've tried your code on SQLite3 with no problem:

(https://gist.github.com/flaviodesousa/1465625173202fda563e)

Comment: SQLite3 maybe I have another issue then. Thanks for looking and ill dig more this week and report back.

Comment: Any luck @VictorioBerra ?

Comment: I have not but it might be a while before I work on this again. Is there a way to "close" the question?

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the documentation it appears as though the "withRelated" field is not an option for model.fetchAll as is it for model.fetch. I'm running into this issue myself. If you run knex with the debug : true you can see that it will only query the table you are fetching on, not the relation.

http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetchAll

Comment: IMHO this is a pretty large problem with bookshelf. I want to grab a list of events each with their invite lists. I'm not sure how one would do that without this functionality

Comment: This fixes this issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Bookshelf.js myself but I think, this could be achieved using `Collections` (http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection).

```
var BackfireTriggers = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: BackfireTrigger
});

BackfireTriggers.forge().fetch({ withRelated: 'backfire' }).then(…);
```

Answer (score 1):

First the good news: I can confirm this works with Bookshelf 1.2.0:

```
  let result = await models.packages
    .fetchAll({
      require:     false,
      columns:     [
          'packages.id',
          'packages.name',
      ],
      withRelated: [
        'packageCollections',
      ],
      debug:       false,
    });
```

The bad news: the documentation of this library is not great. This behavior contradicts with the [documentation](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-static-fetchAll).

Another very big gotcha that wasted *many hours* of my time: this ORM does the joining of related entities in the JavaScript process itself, not by using SQL joins. So, if you don't include the primary key column or foreign key column that is used for any sort of joining, you won't get the relevant related data at all.

**There won't be any error or warning - of course**. You'll just be left wondering, what the heck is happening?
So, yeah, make sure you include the relevant ID.

And if you can - please, just use a different ORM.